# Meaning of 「つりたくない者が、つるわけない」 and 「よけいな心配しないで、のびのびと育ってね」

Tags: て-form, phrases, manga

I've come upon a couple of phrases in Doraemon I quite don't understand.

The first is said by Nobita's mother, trying to calm Nobita down after finding him freaked out by his first encounter with Doraemon.

She says:

> よけいな心配しないで、のびのびと育ってね。

I don't quite get the て form at the end.  Shouldn't it be 育った (`you were raised`)? Also, I wonder if that is a quotation と?

The second is a bit further on, when Nobita is trying to convince himself that there's nothing to worry about after Doraemon's prediction that he would be hanged in 30 minutes time.  He says:

> つりたくない者が、つるわけない。

Would it be something like `Even though I don't want to hang, there's no reason to think I will.`?

---

Image of both pages:

- [First sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU005.jpg)
- [Second sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oaenn.jpg)

Comment: Two problems in as many lines.  (1) Does it say 「のびたのびと」?  Makes no sense unless the mom is making a pun.  (2) Does it really say 「物」?

Comment: (1) I think it does
(2) Sorry, that was a typo, it says 者

I'll link both pages on the original post.

Comment: (1) It does not; Please read carefully.  I would not have asked if what you wrote were the correct word.

Comment: Sorry about that, corrected it. Now I have another question... is that a quotation と?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> よけいな心配しないで、のびのびと育ってね。

て form at the end of a sentence serves as a command form. The と is a case particle, のびのび is a mimetic word and adverb. The と can be left off.

> つりたくない者が、つるわけない。

Anyone who doesn't want to hang himself, can't possibly hang himself.

Comment: So she commands him to not worry and grow up carefree?  Also, what does と exactly mark in that sentence, even though its not necessary?

Comment: She's saying "I want you to grow up carefree/freely". Both のびのび育つ and のびのびと育つ are possible. For the usage of と see definition 5 in http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154670/m0u/%E3%81%A8/ （副詞に付いて新たな副詞をつくり）ある状態を説明する意を表す。(The と is added to an adverb to form another adverb describing a state/condition.)

Comment: I'm afraid my level of Japanese doesn't allow me to understand a monolingual dictionary, but well, if the と particle isn't necessary in that situation, I won't fret over it.  Thanks for the answer.